# How to Show data in GridView TextBox, and/or DropDownListBoxs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My client has given one requirement like below:

He wants to Insert, Update, Delete record inside the GridView only. He wants all the data to be present in TextBoxes and DropDownList controls (i.e. not in the label controls). If he wants to update any record, then he wants to straight-away update the record there and clicks on Update button. He doesn't want to click on the Edit link to get the record in Edit mode.

How can I achieve this functionality? I should also consider references columns while designing GridView. i.e. some templates will contain DropDownList items also.

Can anybody please suggest me how to do this. Some suggestions or some links to learn are appreciatable.

Please help me on this.

Comment: You can invest some cash into a third party rich controls library and do not spent a lot of time to give it working (I mean really nice solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GvYou can add the requied field to the grid view in a template field

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fieldname" >
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txbType" Text='<%# Eval("field") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and then in the backend code

```
 protected void Gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
           int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex.ToString());
           GridViewRow row = GV.Rows[index];
           var txbName = row.FindControl("txbType") as TextBox;            
           string name = "";
           if (txbName != null)
           {
              name = txbName.Text.Trim();
           }
           if (true)
                // your update function          
        }
```

same for the deleting

```
protected void Gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply kasun. I have DropDownList controls also inside the Grid. As you suggested, I will add them inside the <ItemTemplate>, but how can I pull the data into DropDownList control while page/grid is loading?

Comment: use the  GvRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) event and inside that you can add data to each dropdown list eg.  var ddl = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl("dropdonlistid");
            if(ddl != null)   
            {
                
            }           if this is working please accept the answer

Comment: Hi kasun, I have done like this only, but I am not getting results into DropDownList control. How can I show you the code?

Comment: GridView1_RowDataBound{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
DropDownList ddlDeptName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlDeptName") as DropDownList;
if (ddlDeptName != null)
{
  ddlDeptName.DataSource = DepartmentList;
  ddlDeptName.DataTextField = "DNAME";
  ddlDeptName.DataValueField = "DEPTNO";
}
}
}
In .aspx page:
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept Name">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDeptName" runat="server" DataTextField="DeptName" DataValueField="DeptNo"></asp:DropDownList>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this link: http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/08/09/adding-dynamic-rows-in-asp.net-gridview-control-with-textboxes-and.aspx. 
In this example author used only TextBoxes but DropDownList can be used in similar fashion, from the link you will at least get the idea about using control inside GridView cell and then retrieving the data they contains.

Comment: Does this design (Insert, Update, Delete record inside the GridView)Downgrade the performance or not?